# Almost Vandermonde determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

\begin{vmatrix}5- 3 \cdot 2^4   &  2^1 & 2^2 &  2^3  \\ 
 10 - 3 \cdot 3^4 &  3^1 & 3^2 &  3^3  \\ 
 2 -3 (-1)^4  &  (-1)^1 &(-1)^2 & (-1)^3  \\ 
37-3(-6)^4   & (-6)^1 &  (-6)^2 & (-6)^3  \\ \end{vmatrix}

This is a determinant that came up while I was doing a problem.. it has almost the structure of the Vandermonde determinant but I can't see if there are easy simplifications. Any help/ hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy if you see $5=2^2+1$.

$\begin{vmatrix}5- 3 \cdot 2^4   &  2^1 & 2^2 &  2^3  \\ 
 10 - 3 \cdot 3^4 &  3^1 & 3^2 &  3^3  \\ 
 2 -3 (-1)^4  &  (-1)^1 &(-1)^2 & (-1)^3  \\ 
37-3(-6)^4   & (-6)^1 &  (-6)^2 & (-6)^3  \\ \end{vmatrix} = $

$\begin{vmatrix}  2^4   &  2^1 & 2^2 &  2^3  \\ 
  3^4 &  3^1 & 3^2 &  3^3  \\ 
 (-1)^4  &  (-1)^1 &(-1)^2 & (-1)^3  \\ 
(-6)^4   & (-6)^1 &  (-6)^2 & (-6)^3  \\ \end{vmatrix}\cdot (-3)+$

$\begin{vmatrix}2^2   &  2^1 & 2^2 &  2^3  \\ 
 3^2 &  3^1 & 3^2 &  3^3  \\ 
 (-1)^2  &  (-1)^1 &(-1)^2 & (-1)^3  \\ 
(-6)^2   & (-6)^1 &  (-6)^2 & (-6)^3  \\ \end{vmatrix} +$

$\begin{vmatrix}1   &  2^1 & 2^2 &  2^3  \\ 
 1 &  3^1 & 3^2 &  3^3  \\ 
 1 &  (-1)^1 &(-1)^2 & (-1)^3  \\ 
1  & (-6)^1 &  (-6)^2 & (-6)^3  \\ \end{vmatrix}
$

Comment: Nice, this is clever.

Comment: unbelievable solution.. isn't the second one after simplification zero?

Comment: You are right, the matrix has same columns.

Comment: You maybe interested in where it came from :-) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3860206/let-fx-be-a-polynomial-satisfying-lim-x-to-infty-frac-x4-fxx81/3860251#3860251)

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad I helped.

Answer (score 1):

Do an expansion down the first column, then you have subdeterminants to calculate that ARE all essentially Vandermonde.

What I mean:

$$\begin{vmatrix}5- 3 \cdot 2^4   &  2^1 & 2^2 &  2^3  \\ 
 10 - 3 \cdot 3^4 &  3^1 & 3^2 &  3^3  \\ 
 2 -3 (-1)^4  &  (-1)^1 &(-1)^2 & (-1)^3  \\ 
37-3(-6)^4   & (-6)^1 &  (-6)^2 & (-6)^3  \\ \end{vmatrix} 
= (5-3\cdot2^{4}) 
\begin{vmatrix}  
3^1 & 3^2 &  3^3  \\ 
(-1)^1 &(-1)^2 & (-1)^3  \\ 
(-6)^1 &  (-6)^2 & (-6)^3  \\ \end{vmatrix} + \ldots \\
= (5-3\cdot2^{4})\cdot3\cdot(-1)\cdot(-6)
\begin{vmatrix}  
1 & 3 &  3^2  \\ 
1 &(-1) & (-1)^2  \\ 
1 &  (-6) & (-6)^2  \\ \end{vmatrix} + \ldots$$

(Also, since this is a $4\times 4$ matrix it should be easy to compute the determinant without any special tricks).